# Android: File/Folder Encryption

Tags: android, file, encryption

Context: I'm developing a personal safety app in Kotlin. I need to add a feature such that on clicking a button, all images (or associated folders) on a device are encrypted. Decryption requires a passkey, which was used for encryption.

Question: Is there a way to do this through the standard libraries? If not, Is there an API that can help me get this done?

Links will be helpful.

Comment: The simple answer is "Yes". The workflow goes as follows: 1) read an image from external storage, input a passphrase, encrypt file using (e.g.) AES-256 in GCM mode with key derivation (e.g.) PBKDF2, store the encrypted file and delete the original one. For decryption go the other way, input the passphrase, derive the decryption key, load the encrypted file and store it as decrypted one in external storage (and delete the encrypted one). All encryption functions are available with (e.g.) BouncyCastle lib.

Comment: That's actually quite helpful. Do you have a sample code for BouncyCastle ? I haven't worked with the lib before..

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have very less experience in file management on Android and I can't help you in this case [that's why I gave "pseudo code" instead of Java/Kotlin one), sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink the feature, and the need for it.  If you want to encrypt your device, Android has disk encryption as an option.  Use it.  Then set a pass key and/or biometric authorization to open the phone.  That combo is going to be far more secure than your app ever could be.

In the end I doubt what you want to do is possible.  You'd need read/write permissions to folders you won't be able to get them for (every app's private directories).  Encryption also takes time, so you'll never be able to encrypt GBs of data instantly on push of a button.  The right thing to do is to encrypt at all times, so its done when writing to the disk the first time.

You're doing this at the wrong level basically.  This type of behavior needs to be built into the OS (and really already is), not be an app.

Comment: I feel that encrypting the entire device will take a lot of time and power, and it's not really something that can be done on the run.....so I was trying to create a lighter version of the same thing, but, only for images that might be a few hundred MBs at maximum. Like, not the social media pictures, but the camera pictures, and other such folders. 

I'm not looking to encrypt the entire device. It's just the images in the main media directory. More like a file locker app, essentially.

Comment: @MayankGupta Encryption is by default enabled on all recent Google Android devices, therefore it does not require any time because it is always active!

Comment: @Robert are you talking about the standard encryption that takes place while storing a file in the internal storage ? Because the question is completely different from that....

I want to allow a user to encrypt their pictures so that no other person can view it, even when they have access to the device. The said user can later on decrypt those pictures on obtaining their device back, through a passkey that will be sent to one of their contacts as a text message. The pictures I'm talking of aren't in the app's storage, but in the main storage.